# Symbol not found in flat namespace '___kmpc_barrier'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I faced this problem when I import jetnet.
[image]

> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Laptop/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wasserstein/_wasserstein_omp.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '___kmpc_barrier'

Initially I suspect it was due to my problem of install jetnet, so I reinstall jetnet and HDF5. I also switched to different python versions. However, I still face this error.

Comment: The problem is with package named "wasserstein". It's written in C and cannot find some symbols in its dynamic library.